# Как обновить div через AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

На сайте есть блок с контентом который приходит средствам API с другого сервера.
И чтобы увидеть изминение этого контента постоянно нужно обновлять страницу.
как сделать так чтобы этот контент обновлялся сам без перезагрузки самой страницы.
Вот для того чтобы увидеть изменение значения в div нужно каждый раз обновлять страницу.
Ка же сделать чтобы эти значения обновлялись без перезагрузки страницы?

```
<?php
    $url = file_get_contents('https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/ltc-usd');
    $content = json_decode($url, true);
    $result =  $content['ticker']['price'];
    ?>
<div class="result" id="result"> <? echo $result; ?> </div>
```

Comment: Теоретически: Создать отдельную страницу которая будет отдавать только ответ. Посредством js, за определенный срок, скажем 5-10 сек, отправлять запрос и выводит его в этот блок

Answer (score 1):

Скрипт будет каждые 5000 милисекунд(5 секунд) обновлять информацию в `div#result`.

Чтобы менять цвета, когда новый прайс больше старого и меньше старого на красный и зеленый соответственно, нужно будет сохранять каждый раз предыдущий результат. Создадим глобальную переменную `price` и запишем в него текущий результат и при получении нового результата сверим с `price` и выведем соответствующий цвет.

P.S. При первом запросе и в случае совпадении значений старого результата и нового, `div#result` будет бесцветным.

```js
var price;
var reloadData = function() {
  $.getJSON('https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/ltc-usd', function(data){
    var float = parseFloat(data.ticker.price).toFixed(2)
    if(price && price > float) {
        $('#result').html('<font color="red">' + float + '</font>')
    }
    else if(price && price < float) {
        $('#result').html('<font color="green">' + float + '</font>')
    }
    else {
        $('#result').text(float)
    }
    price = float
  })
}

setInterval('reloadData()', 5000)
$(document).ready(reloadData)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: А как после запятой отображать только 2 символа ?
Знаю что через .toFixed(2) можно , но куда его тут поставить , без понятия

Comment: @Encode_VI обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое )) Заработало)))

Comment: Ребятки, не судите строго, учусь пока.
А как сделать так чтобы если значение растёт , текст становиться зелёным, а если значение падает то текст становиться красным

Comment: @Encode_VI еще раз обновил ответ

Comment: если копирую эту функцию для других дивов то работатет только последний. Почему? в чем ошибка

Comment: если я копирую эту функцию для других дивов , работает только последний почему-то, хотя я меняю значение id, в чем проблема? как решить ее